# Local Storage values not found first time. After reload its work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

const AuthGurd=props=>{
   const {children,fallback} = props;
   const auth = useAuth();
   const router=useRouter();
   useEffect(()=>{
    if(!router.isReady){
     return
    }
    if(auth.user===null && !window.localStorage.getItem('userData')){
        if(router.asPath !=='/'){
            router.replace({
            pathname:'/login',
            query:{returnUrl:router.asPath}
            })
        }else{
           router.replace('/login')
        }}
    },[router.route])
    if(auth.loading || auth.user===null){
        return fallback //loader
    }
    return <>{children}</>
}
export default AuthGurd;
```

I am trying to use authentication in my project. when running project first-time localstroage not found its return fallback which is loader. Then I have to refresh the page then return to login page.

Comment: can you try including `auth.user` as useEffect dependency

Comment: Yes but not working

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be localStorage is not defined in the window object yet.

That means you have to wait until the page is successfully mounted.

Please try this

```js
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

const AuthGurd=props=>{
   const {children,fallback} = props;
   const auth = useAuth();
   const router=useRouter();
   const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
   
   useEffect(() => {
     setUserData(window.localStorage.getItem('userData'))
   }, [])
   
   useEffect(()=>{
    if(!router.isReady || !userData){
     return
    }
    if(auth.user===null && !userData){
        if(router.asPath !=='/'){
            router.replace({
            pathname:'/login',
            query:{returnUrl:router.asPath}
            })
        }else{
           router.replace('/login')
        }}
    },[router.route])
    if(auth.loading || auth.user===null){
        return fallback //loader
    }
    return <>{children}</>
}
export default AuthGurd;
```

The important idea is to ensure that localStorage is ready to use after the page is mounted.